# UITableView is not populated because tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is never invoked

Tags: objective-c, ios

My UITableView is not populated because:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is never invoked.

This is how I initialize the table:

```
self.recentScannedItems = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:kLastScannedPortrait style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    [self.recentScannedItems setDelegate:self];
    [self.recentScannedItems setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:recentScannedItems];
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: What do you return from `numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: Are you sure that the recent scanned items contains something... Most probably it's never been called just 'cause `numberOfRowsInSection:` return 0 counting elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented correctly the datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return NumberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return NumberOfRows;
}
```

If you are not implementing this methods, or if you are returning 0 in them, cellForRowAtIndexPath won't be called

Answer (score 0):

Does your class comply to `UITableViewDataSource`? Like:

```
@interface mySuperClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Yes, it is complying to it. By the way, this is just for the compiler it should work even if it is missing I believe. Not solved yet...